# How to play audio from a flutter app terminated app state triggered by a FCM notification?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to play an audio when the app is in terminated state when a FCM notification receives. I don't want to use Local Notifications package coz I want the user to pause the audio by opening the app and click pause.

How do I do this ?

This is the FCM code I tried but It's not working.

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';


  void playMusic() {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  audioPlayer.play('path_to_your_music_file.mp3', isLocal: true);
}


Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Fcm--> title ${message.notification?.title}");
  print("Fcm--> body ${message.notification?.body}");
  print("Fcm--> payload ${message.data}");
  playMusic();

}

class FcmNotifications {
  final fcmInstance = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    //  request permission ---
    NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      print('FCM Token: $fcmToken');
      print("Notifications Initialized");
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((mesg) {
      print("mesg ${mesg}");
    });
  }
}
```